# mysql trigger not making inserts and updates

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger that installs without error, but does not make the expected update and insert.

Bit of background. There are four tables: orders, customers, customer_purchases and uflex_users. Here's the last 3 tables.

```
    CREATE TABLE `customers` (
 `customerID` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billingAddress` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billingAddress1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billingCity` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billingState` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billingZip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billingCountry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `billingPhone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingCompany` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingAddress` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingAddress1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingCity` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingState` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingZip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingCountry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shippingPhone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`),
 CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMERS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`) REFERENCES `uFlex_users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (`email`) REFERENCES `uFlex_users` (email)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `customer_purchases` (
  `customerID` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_PURCHASES_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`) REFERENCES `uFlex_users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`orderNumber`) REFERENCES `orders` (`orderNumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uFlex_users` (
  `user_id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `activated` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `confirmation` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `reg_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_id` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There is a trigger that inserts CustomerID and email into customers after insert into uflex_users and that works fine.

This is the trigger that has the issue.

```
    DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER sstage_ord.ORDERS_TO_CUSTOMER_TABLES_CHECK_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON sstage_ord.orders
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.name != '' AND
    NEW.email != '' AND
    NEW.address1 != '' AND
    NEW.city != '' AND
    NEW.state != '' AND
    NEW.zip != '' AND
    NEW.phone != '' AND
    NEW.country != '' AND
    NEW.shipAddress1 != '' AND
    NEW.shipCity != '' AND
    NEW.shipState != '' AND
    NEW.shipZip != '' AND
    NEW.shipPhone != '' AND
    NEW.shipCountry != ''
  THEN
    SET @myEmail = (SELECT email FROM sstage_ord.customers WHERE email = NEW.email);
    SET @myCity = (SELECT billingCity FROM sstage_ord.customers WHERE email = NEW.email);
      IF @myEmail != NULL && @myCity IS NULL
      THEN 
        UPDATE sstage_ord.customers 
        SET
          name = NEW.name, company = NEW.company, billingAddress = NEW.address1, billingAddress1 = NEW.address2, billingCity = NEW.city,
          billingState = NEW.state, billingZip = NEW.zip, billingCountry = NEW.country, billingPhone = NEW.phone, shippingName = NEW.shipName,
          shippingCompany = NEW.shipCompany, shippingAddress = NEW.shipAddress1, shippingAddress1 = NEW.address2, shippingCity = NEW.shipCity,
         shippingState = NEW.shipState, shippingZip = NEW.shipZip, shippingCountry = NEW.shipCountry, shippingPhone = NEW.shipPhone
        WHERE
          email = NEW.email;
      END IF;

    SET @myID = (SELECT user_id FROM uFlex_users WHERE email = NEW.email);
    IF @myID != NULL
    THEN
      INSERT INTO sstage_ord.customer_purchases (customerID, orderNumber)
      VALUES (@myID, NEW.orderNumber);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue appears to be with the IF statements.

Comment: FWIW, the issues appears to be with the IF statements. Removing those produces the desired results, but I lose my conditions.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Here's the working version:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sstage_ord.ORDERS_TO_CUSTOMER_TABLES_CHECK_INSERT;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER sstage_ord.ORDERS_TO_CUSTOMER_TABLES_CHECK_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON   sstage_ord.orders
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE email_field varchar(50);
  DECLARE city_field varchar(50);
  DECLARE id_field integer;

  IF NEW.orderNumber != '' AND
    NEW.name != '' AND
    NEW.email != '' AND
    NEW.address1 != '' AND
    NEW.city != '' AND
    NEW.state != '' AND
    NEW.zip != '' AND
    NEW.phone != '' AND
    NEW.country != '' AND
    NEW.shipAddress1 != '' AND
    NEW.shipCity != '' AND
    NEW.shipState != '' AND
    NEW.shipZip != '' AND
    NEW.shipPhone != '' AND
    NEW.shipCountry != ''
  THEN

    SELECT email FROM sstage_ord.customers WHERE email = NEW.email INTO email_field;
    SELECT billingCity FROM sstage_ord.customers WHERE email = NEW.email INTO city_field;

    IF email_field IS NOT NULL AND city_field IS NULL THEN 
      UPDATE sstage_ord.customers 
      SET
        name = NEW.name, company = NEW.company, billingAddress = NEW.address1, billingAddress1 = NEW.address2, billingCity = NEW.city,
    billingState = NEW.state, billingZip = NEW.zip, billingCountry = NEW.country, billingPhone = NEW.phone, shippingName = NEW.shipName,
    shippingCompany = NEW.shipCompany, shippingAddress = NEW.shipAddress1, shippingAddress1 = NEW.address2, shippingCity = NEW.shipCity,
    shippingState = NEW.shipState, shippingZip = NEW.shipZip, shippingCountry = NEW.shipCountry, shippingPhone = NEW.shipPhone
      WHERE
        email = NEW.email;
    END IF;

    SELECT user_id FROM sstage_ord.uFlex_users WHERE email = NEW.email INTO id_field;

    IF id_field IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO sstage_ord.customer_purchases (customerID, orderNumber)
      VALUES (id_field, NEW.orderNumber);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```